# Why is the behavior different for `where` versus `select` in pyspark dataframe for version 1.6.1?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `pyspark 1.6.1` and I create a dataframe like so:

```
toy_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('blah',10)], ['name', 'age'])
```

Now, watch what happens when I try to query for `'blah'` in this dataframe using `where` and again using `select`:

```
toy_df_where = toy_df.where(toy_df['name'] != 'blah')
toy_df_where.count()
0
toy_df_select = toy_df.select(toy_df['name'] != 'blah')
toy_df_select.count()
1
```

Why is the result different for these two options?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you coming to this from a relational algebra background? If so I can see the confusion. In SQL (which is where Spark's `select` and `where` comes from), `select` refers to selecting the *columns* you are interested in (or in relational algebra the term is "project"), whereas `where` refers to selecting the *rows* you are interested in (or in relational algebra... "select").

Comment: @JackLeow - enlighten me on the relational algebra background.  I love math and would really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but why does it not throw an error when using select on a boolean evaluated statement?  that is the behavrio I would expect?

Comment: Ah, because a boolean expression is a perfectly valid value for a column. If you had done `toy_df_select.show()`, you'd just see a bunch of rows with the values `true`/`false` (or in your specific example, one row, whose value is `true`).

Comment: As to relational algebra, you can probably Google for more details, but here's the Wikipedia article on projection - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra), and selection - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(relational_algebra). I learnt about it in this online course - https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/2014/SelfPaced/about

Comment: oh oh.  gotcha, thanks @JackLeow!!

Answer (score 2):

`where` as well as `filter` is used to filter rows, while `select` is used to select columns, so in your select statement, `toy_df['name'] != 'blah'` constructs a new column with boolean values and the select method selects it into the result data frame, or more clearly see this example:

```
>>> toy_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('blah',10), ('foo', 20)], ['name', 'age'])

>>> toy_df_where = toy_df.where(toy_df['name'] != 'blah')
>>> toy_df_where.show()
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| foo| 20|
+----+---+

# filter works the same way as where
>>> toy_df_filter = toy_df.filter(toy_df['name'] != 'blah')
>>> toy_df_filter.show()
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
| foo| 20|
+----+---+

>>> toy_df_select = toy_df.select((toy_df['name'] != 'blah').alias('cond'))
# give the column a new name with alias
>>> toy_df_select.show()
+-----+
| cond|
+-----+
|false|
| true|
+-----+
```